# Given 2 objects: myPanel1 & myPanel2, If we add myPanel2 into myPanel1 many times, then why myPanel1.getWidgetCount() still = 1;

Tags: java, gwt

This code is in Gwt but if u just know Java then u still can be able to answer this question.

Ok, i have 2 panels: myPanel1 & myPanel2, then I add myPanel2 into myPanel1 many times

```
myPanel1.add(myPanel2);
myPanel1.add(myPanel2);
myPanel1.add(myPanel2);
myPanel1.add(myPanel2);
....
```

Then I count the number of Widgets in `myPanel1`

```
System.out.println("No of Widgets inside myPanel1: "+ myPanel1.getWidgetCount());
```

The result is "`No of Widgets inside myPanel1: 1`"

Why number of Widgets inside myPanel1 is still 1 even though we added myPanel2 into myPanel1 many times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a GWT developer, but I suspect this is calling [`Panel.add(Widget)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html#add%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29) which documents these steps (emphasis mine):

> There are several important things that must take place in the correct order to properly add or insert a Widget to a Panel. Not all of these steps will be relevant to every Panel, but all of the steps must be considered.
>
> 1. Validate: Perform any sanity checks to ensure the Panel can accept a new Widget. Examples: checking for a valid index on insertion; checking that the Panel is not full if there is a max capacity.
> 2. Adjust for Reinsertion: Some Panels need to handle the case where the Widget is already a child of this Panel. Example: when performing a reinsert, the index might need to be adjusted to account for the Widget's removal. See ComplexPanel.adjustIndex(Widget, int).
> 3. **Detach Child: Remove the Widget from its existing parent, if any. Most Panels will simply call Widget.removeFromParent() on the Widget.**
> 4. Logical Attach: Any state variables of the Panel should be updated to reflect the addition of the new Widget. Example: the Widget is added to the Panel's WidgetCollection at the appropriate index.
> 5. Physical Attach: The Widget's Element must be physically attached to the Panel's Element, either directly or indirectly.
> 6. Adopt: Call adopt(Widget) to finalize the add as the very last step.

In other words, when you add something to one panel, it's removed from whatever panel it's *currently* part of, if any.

To be honest, it's not clear what effect you expected anyway - you've still only got two objects... what would it *mean* for a single widget to be in a panel multiple times? If you want multiple widgets, create multiple objects.

Comment: i asked cos I got a wrong code but it's still working. That is I put the add(myPanel2) into a loop & still didn't see any problem